# Issues getting my profile picture in a Flash application

Tags: php, facebook, flash, profile, image

I have a PHP script that returns to me my (and my friends) profile pictures, using the following:

`http://graph.facebook.com/".$ID."/picture?type=large`
where $ID is the ID retrieved using the PHP API. I then use the following for loading the images in my app:

```
public function LoadProfile()
{
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUrlLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(ImageURL));
    //ImageURL is the URL provided by the PHP Script
    // which is the 'http://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/picture?type=large'
}
private function onUrlLoaded(event:Event)
{           
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUrlLoaded);

    var path:String = LoaderInfo(event.target).url;

    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onReallyComplete);
    var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);
    lc.checkPolicyFile = true;
    loader.load(new URLRequest(path), lc);
}
private function onReallyComplete(event:Event)
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onReallyComplete);
}
```

This works for ALL of my friends, but does NOT work for me for some reason. I get the following general address for the image of my friends:

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/370825_524761447_653077984_n.jpg

But for me I just get

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net

which is some random person ... NOT me ...

I've verified repeatedly that the ID being sent back from the PHP is in-fact my ID, and I've copy/pasted the address traced BEFORE the loading function into a browser and I get my correct profile picture, but somewhere in there it's bugging out for my ID in the load and only my ID in the load (I should rephrase it to say it bugs out for WHATEVER user is logged in to Facebook, not just me).

Any ideas? Or anyone know of an alternative way to get MY profile picture?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function loadProfile():void
{
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, loader_securityErrorHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loader_ioErrorHandler);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(_imageURL));
}

private function loader_securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(event.toString());
}

private function loader_ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(event.toString());
}

private function loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, loader_securityErrorHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loader_ioErrorHandler);

    addChild(loader);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work on Facebook -- it works on my local client if I run it from Flash Pro, but when I upload to Facebook it freezes. I had this problem before, that's why I ended up going with the code I posted above. The code you provided gives a "Security Error 2122" from Facebook. The code I found was a solution to the 2122 Error that I found using some fancy Google searches.

Comment: Go to File -> Publish settings -> Flash. Then set "Local playback" to "Access network only".

Comment: Emin, can the "Local playback" setting really effect a swf that is "uploaded to Facebook"?

Comment: That didn't work -- still can't get my profile picture to load.

Comment: Is there any way to access my profile picture outside of the Graph API?